# Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

`manifest.json`

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Monitoring",
  "description": "Testing Plugin",
  "version": "0.1.0", 
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["extension.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "externally_connectable": {  
    "matches": ["*://teamsqa.educore.guru/*"]
  },
  "permissions": ["desktopCapture" 
  ] 
}
```

Extension.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
//response
    const sources = message.sources;
    const tab = sender.tab;
   chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(sources, tab, (streamId) => {  //stream
    if (!streamId) {
            sendResponse({
              type: 'error',
              message: 'Failed to get stream ID'
            });
          } else {
           
            sendResponse({
              type: 'success',
              streamId: streamId
            });
          }
    });
    return true;
});
```

index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>share your  Screen</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Screen</h1>
  <button id="share-it">share</button>
<video autoplay id="screen-view" width="50%"></video>
  <script  >
//script
   (() => {
    const EXTENSION_ID = 'bnldcjfgiecgggogiggnpfagbdegmplb';
    const share = document.getElementById('share-it');
    const video = document.getElementById('screen-view');
    const request = { 
    sources: [ 'screen']
      };
    let stream;
//click event to listner
  share.addEventListener('click', event => { 
      window.chrome.runtime.sendMessage(EXTENSION_ID, request, response => 
     {   //response
          if (response && response.type === 'success') {
          navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            video: {
              mandatory: {
                chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
                chromeMediaSourceId: response.streamId
              }
            } //stream video
          }).then(returnedStream => {
            stream = returnedStream;
           video.srcObject = stream;
          }).catch(err => {
            console.error('Could not get stream: ', err);
         });
        } else {
          console.error('Could not get stream');
        }
      });
    });
 })();
  </script>
</body> 
</html>
```

This is my manifest file when i connect extension from teamsqa.educore.guru its through error
Can you help me?
I updated my extension.js here too
And also Intex.html file . here am upload my html file to my domain and send request to extension and the error shows that " Receiving end does not exist chrome extension"

Comment: Here is my extension.js file @wOxxOm

Comment: extension.js is fine, and what about the connect code?

Comment: index.html is my connect code @wOxxOm

Comment: on localhost it work fine

Comment: Seems fine too. Maybe `matches` has a typo or a mistake? Another thing to check: open `chrome://policy` and see if it has ExtensionSettings.

Comment: matches and policy are fine

Comment: Maybe you were debugging extension.js so the background script was paused in devtools?

Comment: i decided to change my video tag from index to another page can you please tell how can i do it?

Comment: i used navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia() without the help of extension we can capture screen